# How to convert this XML file to CSV using python?

Tags: python, xml, csv, xpath, elementtree

I have hereby the attached the xml file I am trying to convert to csv

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <data>
    <shops>
      <shop id="204019">
        <name>Bannockburn</name>
        <status>Open</status>
        <company id="25">Franchise</company>
        <shopAttributes>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_OPEN_DATE">2008-07-16</shopAttribute>
          <shopAttribute attrName="CLOSE_DATE"/>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_DISTRIBUTION_CTR_GENERAL" startDate="2019-03-19">90</shopAttribute>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_DISTRIBUTION_CTR_GENERAL" startDate="1900-01-01" endDate="2019-03-18"/>
        </shopAttributes>
        <addresses>
          <address type="PUBLIC">
            <addressLine1>1211 Half Day Road</addressLine1>
            <addressLine2></addressLine2>
            <city>Bannockburn</city>
            <stateProvince>IL</stateProvince>
            <postalCode>60015</postalCode>
            <country>USA</country>
            <latitude>42.199461</latitude>
            <longitude>-87.860582</longitude>
          </address>
        </addresses>
      </shop>
      <shop id="204020">
        <name>Plainfield - North Plainfield</name>
        <status>Open</status>
        <company id="25">Franchise</company>
        <shopAttributes>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_OPEN_DATE">2007-05-18</shopAttribute>
          <shopAttribute attrName="CLOSE_DATE"/>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_DISTRIBUTION_CTR_GENERAL" startDate="2019-03-19">90</shopAttribute>
          <shopAttribute attrName="shop_DISTRIBUTION_CTR_GENERAL" startDate="1900-01-01" endDate="2019-03-18"/>
        </shopAttributes>
        <addresses>
          <address type="PUBLIC">
            <addressLine1>12632 IL Route 59</addressLine1>
            <addressLine2>Suite #102</addressLine2>
            <city>Plainfield</city>
            <stateProvince>IL</stateProvince>
            <postalCode>60585</postalCode>
            <country>USA</country>
            <latitude>41.653125</latitude>
            <longitude>-88.204527</longitude>
          </address>
        </addresses>
      </shop>
</shops>
</data>
</response>
```

this is the xml file I want to convert to csv, can someone help me how to do it in python?
Below is the code that I tried to use but I haven't really understood how to do it, saw some examples but it isn't very clear

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('Store.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for att in root:
    first = att.find('shops').text
    print('{}'.format(first))
```

but i was getting None here.

Comment: Google: i.e. have a look here:
https://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I have seen this, and when I tried to use this. I got an empty csv so I thought there must be something i am missing.

Comment: What information are you trying to get? Shops has no text, so it would only print blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution but in answer to why you were getting `None`, it's because your shops are actually one level deeper, under the `data` tag.

This bit of code might give you an idea of how to access the underlying attributes, which you can collect into a list or other container to build your CSV.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('Store.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = root.find('data')

for shops in data:
    for shop in shops:
        name = shop.find('name').text
        sid = shop.attrib
        status = shop.find('status').text
        attrs = shop.find('shopAttributes')
        open_date = attrs.find(".//shopAttribute/[@attrName='shop_OPEN_DATE']").text
        print(f"Name: {name}, ID: {sid}, Status: {status}, open: {open_date}")
```

The `open_date` is an example of how to use [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to access attributes. The code returns:

```
Name: Bannockburn, ID: {'id': '204019'}, Status: Open, open: 2008-07-16
Name: Plainfield - North Plainfield, ID: {'id': '204020'}, Status: Open, open: 2007-05-18
```

Comment: The explanation as well as the links attached were really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No probs! I remember struggling with element tree way back when.. it was a good review!  There might be better ways to do it if you want more complex behaviour though. =)

Answer (score 0):

Shops has no text, so it’ll print nothing. You need to get down to the level you want

```
for att in root.findall('./data/shops/shop’):
    first = att.find('name')
    print('{}'.format(first.text))
```

Gives

```
Bannockburn
Plainfield - North Plainfield
```

Here is a good resource for ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html